# How do I extract RGB color values from an image using Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to extract color values from an image using color_thief_flutter but it throws an error What should I do to extract rgb color values from images?

```
import 'package:color_thief_flutter/color_thief_flutter.dart';
import 'package:color_thief_flutter/utils.dart';
import 'package:flutter/painting.dart';


void main() {

  // color_thief_flutter.dart

  final url = 'https://github.githubassets.com/images/modules/open_graph/github-octocat.png';

  getColorFromUrl(url).then((color) {
    print(color); // [R,G,B]
  });
}
```

I got an error What should I do.

```
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY IMAGE RESOURCE SERVICE ╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following _CastError was thrown while resolving an image:
Null check operator used on a null value
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a combination of the [`image`](https://pub.dev/packages/image) and `http` packages would be far superior to using `color_thief_flutter`.

```yaml
dependencies:
  image: ^3.0.2
  http: ^0.13.3
```

The following code obtains a list of the colors in the image at the specified url and has inline comments describing how it works:

```dart
import 'package:http/http.dart';
import 'package:image/image.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  final url = 'https://github.githubassets.com/images/modules/open_graph/github-octocat.png';
  final resp = await get(Uri.parse(url)); //Download the image data from the url
  final img = resp.bodyBytes;

  final decodedImg = decodeImage(img); //Decode the received image data
  if(decodedImg == null) {
    throw 'Invalid image';
  }

  final bytesList = decodedImg.data;
  final colorList = bytesList.map<Color>((e) => Color(e)).toList();//Map the decoded data to colors

  //Change format to a 2d list of colors so that they can be accessed as colorGrid[x][y]
  final List<List<Color>> colorGrid = [];
  for(int x = 0; x < decodedImg.width; x++) {
    colorGrid.add([]);
    for(int y = 0; y < decodedImg.height; y++) {
      colorGrid[x].add(colorList[x + y * decodedImg.width]);
    }
  }

  print(colorGrid);
}

/// Stores RGBA values
class Color {
  final int alpha, blue, green, red;

  Color(int abgr) : 
    alpha = abgr >> 24 & 0xFF,
    blue = abgr >> 16 & 0xFF,
    green = abgr >> 8 & 0xFF,
    red = abgr & 0xFF;

  @override
  String toString() {
    return 'R: $red, G: $green, B: $blue, A: $alpha';
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much, what if I want to import an image and extract RGB, L*a*b* color values from the image by pixel assignment?

Comment: @zeewa42 what is Lab?

Comment: L*,a*,b* = CIELAB

Comment: @zeewa42 That's out of the scope of your question. You asked *explicitly* for RGB, not CIELAB. If my answer helped you "extract rgb color values" I recommend accepting it and asking a new question asking how to convert RGB to CIELAB in Dart.